# CTRL+ALT hides active window after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: unity, keyboard

Somethig weird is going on after I upgaded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> (yes, just these two keys together, nothing else) then the current active window disappears. It can only be restored after clicking on the appropriate icon in the launch bar.

I thought at first the problem might be with the hot key assignment for "minimise window" and tried to redefine it, but nothing changed.

Funny that even the hot key dialog window desappears whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> inside of it. So I cannot effectively assign any hot key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> in it.

Note that the way the window disappears when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is different from when I minimise it. So these two are probably not related, even though the result is similar.

Any thoughts on what might cause this weird behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is some mess in key bindings of a window manager in Unity. I've found controversial settings there.

Please try to open `dconf-editor`, navigate to **/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings** and remove association of **toggle-shaded** setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

As a workaround, everytime that I work in a window I maximize it. As soon as the window is maximized it doesn't disappear on that Ctrl+Alt shortcut.

Hope this helps out in the meantime.

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 and this happened.